# LVM Will Not Mount RW

Tags: linux, lvm

I have an LVM that I want to mount up, but for whatever reason I can't get it to mount RW.  It will only mount RO.

Here is the PV.

```
[root@SEAScoutDB01 mnt]# pvdisplay /dev/sda2
  "/dev/sda2" is a new physical volume of "99.51 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda2
  VG Name
  PV Size               99.51 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               vOas0J-dMfE-YYUf-jPu1-0vgX-VJzW-vanf8a
```

Here is the VG.  Note it is read/write.

```
[root@SEAScoutDB01 mnt]# vgdisplay arm
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               arm
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  1
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                0
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               99.51 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              25474
  Alloc PE / Size       0 / 0
  Free  PE / Size       25474 / 99.51 GiB
  VG UUID               wEL5E8-I4Yc-MQJQ-rBJG-Fyob-HXJ6-H8ivzh
```

And here is the LV.  Note also it is read/write.

```
[root@SEAScoutDB01 mnt]# lvdisplay arm
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/arm/arm-data
  LV Name                arm-data
  VG Name                arm
  LV UUID                SRK2EO-hm5L-QYyZ-mDMf-ijwn-EkxL-2UhW8g
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time SEAScoutDB01.ohnoez.lan, 2017-02-27 14:19:51 -0800
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                99.51 GiB
  Current LE             25474
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2
```

Here is the device in /dev/mapper

```
[root@SEAScoutDB01 mnt]# ls -l /dev/mapper/*
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root       7 Feb 27 14:19 /dev/mapper/arm-arm--data -> ../dm-2
```

Here I am mounting the file system and being told that my explicitly declared read/write LVM is in fact write-protected.

```
[root@SEAScoutDB01 mnt]# mount -w /dev/dm-2 /mnt/arm-data
mount: /dev/mapper/arm-arm--data is write-protected but explicit `-w' flag given
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if you're allowed to mount LVM logical volumes by their device mapper. You should have a device representing your LV. In your case, /dev/arm/arm-data. Have you tried `mount /dev/arm/arm-data /mnt/arm-data`?

Comment: Your `PV` is set to `Allocatable: NO`. Can you try to execute the command as follows and try to mount again. `pvchange -x y /dev/sda2`.

Comment: I tried that.  Wasn't the problem.  The problem was that someone (I'll not name names, but their initials are J.E.R.O.M.E. didn't put a file system on the volume once I created it.

So duh for me, and thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be that I didn't put a file system on the volume once I created it.